# Removing rows where values in a column are not 4 digits long in R

Tags: r, dplyr, data-wrangling

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
example <- data.frame(
  sub = c(23, 6, 1101, 3827, 3098, 289990000, 2245),
  text = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g")
)
```

How can I remove the rows where the values in `sub` that are not 4 digits long?

This is the solution:

```
example_solution <- data.frame(
  sub = c(1101, 3827, 3098, 2245),
  text = c("c", "d", "e", "g")
)
```

Thanks!

Comment: You can use `subset(example, floor(log10(abs(sub)))+1==4)` from the duplicate. It should be easy if you use those methods to find the number of digits first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `subset` + `nchar`

```
> subset(example, nchar(sub) == 4)
   sub text
3 1101    c
4 3827    d
5 3098    e
7 2245    g
```

Answer (score 1):

```
> example[nchar(example$sub)==4, ]
   sub text
3 1101    c
4 3827    d
5 3098    e
7 2245    g
```